# How does the addition of two wavefunctions develop in time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra, density-operator

Two time dependent wavefunctions:

$\Psi _1(t)= \psi_1*exp(\frac{-i * E_1}{\hbar}*t)$

$\Psi _2(t)= \psi_2*exp(\frac{-i * E_2}{\hbar}*t)$

Both a solution to the timeindependent (note "in") Schrödinger eq. with the same H. We know they are solutions. Furthermore $E_1$ and $E_2$ are different.

$\mid \psi_1exp(\frac{-i  E_1}{\hbar}t) + \psi_2exp(\frac{-i  E_2}{\hbar}t)\mid ^2 $

$= \mid \psi_1exp(\frac{-i  E_1}{\hbar}*t)\mid^2 + \mid\psi_2exp(\frac{-i  E_2}{\hbar}t)\mid^2 + 2  \mid\psi_1exp(\frac{-i  E_1}{\hbar}t)  \psi_2exp(\frac{-i  E_2}{\hbar}t) \mid$

$= \mid \psi_1exp(\frac{-i  E_1}{\hbar}*t)\mid^2 + \mid\psi_2exp(\frac{-i  E_2}{\hbar}t)\mid^2 + 2  \mid\psi_1  \psi_2exp(\frac{-i  (E_2-E_1)}{\hbar}t) \mid$

Is the following correct?:

$\mid \psi_1exp(\frac{-i  E_1}{\hbar}*t)\mid^2 = \mid\psi_1^{(*)}\psi_1\mid = \mid\psi_1\mid^2* exp(\frac{-i E_1}{\hbar}t) * exp(\frac{i E_1}{\hbar}t) = \mid\psi_1\mid^2$

leading to:

$\mid \psi_1exp(\frac{-i  E_1}{\hbar}t) + \psi_2exp(\frac{-i  E_2}{\hbar}t)\mid ^2 = \mid\psi_1\mid^2 + \mid\psi_2\mid^2 + 2  \mid\psi_1  \psi_2exp(\frac{-i  (E_2-E_1)}{\hbar}t) \mid$

meaning that: 
$\mid\Psi _1(t)+\Psi _2(t)\mid $ ocilliates with $\frac{\hbar}{(E_2-E_2)}$ ?

Comment: How can those wave functions be solutions of the time independent Schrodinger equation, if they do not depend on the spatial coordinates?

Comment: Sorry I was just to lazy to write $\Psi(r,t)$, but you are right, it should have been said that the wavefunctions depended on the spartial coordinates. Any how it does not change the problem.

Comment: I think what you wrote is right. What's the question?

Comment: If what I wrote was correct, which seems to be the case, which answers my question. thx!

Comment: Related: [Is there oscillating charge in a hydrogen atom?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/293359/is-there-oscillating-charge-in-a-hydrogen-atom)

Comment: Mote that your use of the absolute value for the cross terms us incorrect - that should be the real part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obviously mean that 
$$\begin{aligned}
H\psi_1 &= E_1\psi_1,\\
H\psi_2 &= E_2\psi_2.
\end{aligned}$$
Then, the solution of the Schrödinger equation (I will use units such that $\hbar=1$ throughout: old habit of a former theoretical physicist!!)
$$H\Psi_k = i\dfrac{\partial \Psi_k}{\partial t}$$
with the initial condition
$$\Psi_k(t=0) = \psi_k$$
is indeed your
$$\Psi_k = \psi_k \exp(-iE_k t).$$
Then you consider a superposition of these two states, $\Psi = \Psi_1 + \Psi_2$, which is also solution of the Schrödinger equation for the initial condition
$$\Psi(t=0) = \psi_1 + \psi_2,$$
i.e. a superposition of a state of energy $E_1$ and a state of energy $E_2$.

Your calculation of $|\Psi_1 + \Psi_2|^2$ is a wee bit incorrect:
$$|\Psi_1 + \Psi_2|^2 = |\Psi_1|^2 + |\Psi_2|^2 + \underbrace{\Psi_1 {\Psi_2}^{\!*} + {\Psi_1}^{\!*}\Psi_2}_{2\Re\Psi_1{\Psi_2}^{\!*}}$$
where $\Re$ denotes the real part. That is to say
$$|\Psi_1 + \Psi_2|^2 = |\psi_1|^2 + |\psi_2|^2+2\Re \psi_1{\psi_2}^{\!*}\exp[ i(E_2-E_1)t]$$
This does not change your conclusion though: oscillations with a pulsation $E_2 - E_1$.

Right, now that this is all clear and correct, could you elaborate on your question? I can't guess what you want to know!

Comment: The question was: was my calculation correct. Did I properly undersand the calculation behind the superposition squared.  Your correction of the $\mid\Psi_1+\Psi_2\mid^2$ answered any doubt I had

Comment: Ok! Happy to help!