# What happens to the wavefunction in an allowed transition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

What happens to the wavefunction in an allowed transition when an electron transfers from a higher energy level to a lower energy level inside a one-dimensional box?

Comment: It depends on what we are talking about and what level of physical/mathematical description we use. Please add more specifics to your question.

Comment: Related: [Is there oscillating charge in a hydrogen atom?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/293359/is-there-oscillating-charge-in-a-hydrogen-atom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, assume that there are 2 levels in your system (it can be any system you want as long as the particle can transition between the two). When you shine a light on the system, the particle periodically moves between the two states (if the light is monochromatic and at the wavelength of the transition). So after a certain time T, the particle has a 100% probability of being in the upper state, the wavefunction consists only of the upper state. This is called Rabi Oscillation and you can learn more using these resources:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-974-fundamentals-of-photonics-quantum-electronics-spring-2006/lecture-notes/chapter6.pdf

https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/chab/physical-chemistry/ultrafast-spectroscopy-dam/documents/lectures/advancedkineticsFS16/Exdef/advkin_exercise07.pdf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabi_cycle